# Limit PowerShell VersionInfo output to only 3 decimal places where 4 decimal places are given or Remove Decimal Place in VersionInfo

Tags: powershell, decimal, powershell-2.0, versioninfo

I tried my best to find the answer on my own for almost 2 days before posting. I apologize in advance if this question is already answered somewhere on this site.

In short, I need to pull VersionInfo from a .dll which I am currently doing using:

> [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo('C:\PathHere.dll').FileVersion | New-Item –ItemType file c:\test.txt

This works for me, though if someone has what they feel is a cleaner method, I'm all ears...or more accurately...all eyes. The script will take the full version value and write to to a text file just as I want, but I the problem is that I only want the first 3 decimal places and in this case, I'm getting the full version info which is always 4 decimal places long.

So, if the VersionInfo is 1.3.102310.0345, I want that .txt file to only contain 1.3.102310
It is very important that the number remaining NOT be rounded.

As long as the end result is the full values for those first 3 decimal places, I don't really care if the version output is somehow limited to only display the first 3 decimal places, or if the full versioninfo is recorded to the .txt and then reliably removed from the file.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$value = [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo(...)
$version = [version]$value.ProductVersion
$output = $version.tostring(3) # show x.y.z
$output | out-file c:\test.txt
```

Comment: I think you need this to  work it: $value = [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo(...).ProductVersion - I cant cast a FileVersionInfo to [Version]

Comment: no! it needs: [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo(...).ProductVersion !

Comment: I tried this but was unable to get it to work - undoubtedly, it is user error so I will continue to try it, just to better understand if nothing else. Thank you very much for the quick response and support both manojlds and Cristian.

Comment: Worked for me after replacing the first ToString() with ProductVersion.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
[string]::Join('.', (Get-Item C:\PathHere.dll).versionInfo.FileVersion.Split('.')[0..2]) |  New-Item –ItemType file c:\test.txt
```

Or a regex way in case you want two problems:

```
(Get-Item C:\PathHere.dll).versionInfo.FileVersion -replace '^(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\.\d+$', "`$1" | New-Item –ItemType file c:\test.txt
```

Comment: This works very well and seems much cleaner than the direction I was taking it with a split, select first 3, and re-join (though that method has other applications in what I'm doing). Thank you very much for the incredible answers - both methods will surely be helpful to myself and others looking for a similar solution!

Answer (score 0):

This is another way:

```
$a = [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo('C:\my.dll').fileversion; $a.Substring(0, $a.LastIndexOf('.')) |  New-Item –ItemType file c:\test.txt
```

Comment: Thank you yet again Christian. This absolutely works and again, I appreciate the thorough response and support!

Answer (score 0):

These answers are excellent and all did the trick. After having posted this question, I slowed down, took a step back and while talking to a friend, another possible answer hit me.

> $VersionInfo = [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo('C:\Builds\Agent1\QACodeLine\Sources\WebPublicBuild\Binaries\PowerWallet.Common.CommonTypes.dll').FileVersion
>   $VersionInfo.split('.') | select -first 3 | out-File "C:\testies.txt"

This method first splits the output into 4 parts using the .split('.') and then takes only the first 3 via the select -first 3 (select only the first 3 outputs. The output can then be rejoined or if more useful, saved to a file line by line but I think I will go with one of the methods provided here as in the end, I will be better off writing to a text file with the first 3 octets in their proper version info format.

Thanks again for the speedy responses - the help is very much appreciated! PowerShell is incredible and it's supportive community even more so!